# How to make a loop statement, to get the value from the previous page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm setting up an online quiz/exam page in my website on localhost (for education purposes only). But when checking for the answer it only checks for the second question for the right answer.
e.g There are 2 questions. I chose both correct answers, but at the next page it shows that I got 1 out of 2. ?

I have tried using POST/GET method as well...
but still the same

***Students taking the quiz (Question).php***

```
<?php 

    include("conn.php");
    $quiz_id = intval($_GET['quiz_id']); 
    $display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question WHERE quiz_id = 
    $quiz_id");  


    if (!isset($_POST['Submit']) || ($_POST['Submit'] != 'Mark')) { 

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display)) {  
          echo "<form method=post action='score.php?quiz_id=";
          echo $row['quiz_id'];
          echo "'>";


          echo "<table border=0>";  



          $id = $row["question_id"];    
          $question = $row["questions"];    
          $opt1 = $row["option1"];    
          $opt2 = $row["option2"];    
          $opt3 = $row["option3"];
          $opt4 = $row["option4"];    
          $answer = $row["answer"];   

          echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>";    

          echo "
          <tr>
              <td>$opt1 <input type=radio name='q$id' value=\"$opt1\"></td>
              <td>$opt2 <input type=radio name='q$id' value=\"$opt2\"></td>
              <td>$opt3 <input type=radio name='q$id' value=\"$opt3\"></td>
              <td>$opt4 <input type=radio name='q$id' value=\"$opt4\"></td>
          </tr>
          ";

       }     

       echo "</table>";


       echo "<input type='Submit' name='Submit' value ='Mark'>";  
       echo "</form>";    
    }


    ?>
```

***Score.php (marking the results)***

```
    <?php

    include("conn.php");
    $quiz_id = intval($_GET['quiz_id']); 

    if ($_POST['Submit']) {   

       $display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question WHERE quiz_id = $quiz_id");  
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display)) {

          $id = $row["question_id"];
          $answer = $row["answer"];
          $score = 0;    
          $total = mysqli_num_rows($display);        

          while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($display)) {                            


             $answer = "$result[answer]";            
             $q = "q$result[question_id]";                    
             $q = trim($q);
             if ($_POST[$q] == $answer) {                
                $score++;                 
             }        
          }        

          echo "<p align=center><b>You scored $score out of $total</b></p>";    
          echo "<p>";        
       }
    }
    ?>
```

I expect the results to be 2 out of 2.
But it is showing only 1 out of 2.

UPDATE

```
<?php

include("conn.php");
$quiz_id = intval($_GET['quiz_id']);

//echo 'from form: '.$_POST['q14']; // from form


 if ($_POST['Submit']) {   

$display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question WHERE quiz_id = 
$quiz_id");  

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($display)) { 

$id = $result["question_id"];
$answer = $result["answer"];
$score = 0;    
$total = mysqli_num_rows($display);        




$answer = $result['answer'];            
$q = $result['question_id'];   
echo 'answer: '.$answer;

//echo $q;    
//$q = trim($q);
/* if ($q == $answer) {                
$score++;                 

//echo "<p align=center><b>You scored $score out of $total</b></p>";    
//echo "<p>";  

}
 }
```

?>

Comment: There's a typing mistake in your code, you typed the variables within quotes 
Change it like below
 $answer = $result['answer'];            
    $q =  $result['question_id'];

Comment: You are looping 2 times in your display in Score.php, the error may come from here

Comment: yes you are right. I'm trying to remove one of the loop but there are still errors...

Comment: Could you please show way of removing ?